# Angular: error NG8001: 'component' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use a component ('register') inside the app.component and it throws me this error:

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:88:1 - error NG8001: 'register' is
> not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'register' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> 88

My app.component.html:

```
...
<register></register>
...
```

My register.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  public title:string;

  constructor() {
    this.title = 'Registrar';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Componente de registro cargado');
  }

}
```

My app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'red soc';
}
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `<app-register></app-register>` instead of `<register></register>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is **'app-register'** but you are using **'register'** .

Use **'app-register'** istead of **'register'**

I hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: yep, thank you for the answer. The tutorial I'm learning is old u_u'

Comment: You're welcome buddy.  I learned Angular from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eWrpsCLMJQ&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ .